# str_to_date and concat to unit date and time

Tags: mysql

str_to_date and concat unite function with time and date. I don't know how to change the format to import or after or populate directly when making visits.

```
CREATE trigger `trigger` before insert
    on `int`
    for each row


BEGIN

    declare p, c, v, m, dublare int;
    declare dublare_inreg condition for 1062;
    declare continue handler for dublare_inreg
        begin
            set dublare = 0;    
        end;
    set dublare = 1;
    set foreign_key_checks = 0;



    insert into pacienti(nume,prenume) values(new.numepacient,new.prenumepacient);      

        set p = last_insert_id();
        if dublare = 0 then
            select distinct id_p from pacienti where nume = new.numepacient into p;
            set dublare = 1;

        end if;

    insert into cabinete(den_cabinet) values(new.cabinet);              

        set c = last_insert_id();
        if dublare = 0 then
            select distinct id_c from cabinete where den_cabinet =new.cabinet into c;
            set dublare = 1;

        end if;

        set m = last_insert_id();
      if dublare = 0 then
        select distinct id_m from medici where id_m = nume into m;
            set dublare = 1;
      end if;

    INSERT INTO vizite(data_ora,id_cabinet,id_pacienti,id_medici) 
        values(str_to_date(new.datavizita, ' ' , new.oraintrare, '%d / %m / %Y %H:%i:%s')), p , c , m);
```

In my csv file i have format data 22/02/2016

And this is my load.

```
  load data local infile 'D:\\pfinal\\vizite.txt' IGNORE into table `int` 
                                fields terminated by ','
                                lines terminated by '\n'
                                ignore 190000 lines
                                (DataVizita,OraIntrare,NumePacient,PrenumePacient,NumeMedic,PrenumeMedic,Cabinet)
                            ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces in your date format, they dont exist in your input date, and use CONCAT to amalgamate the date and time fields

```
str_to_date(CONCAT(new.datavizita,' ',new.oraintrare),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: One more problem, i want to change the fromat " str_to_date(CONCAT(new.datavizita,' ',new.oraintrare),'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') " and when i want to insert that give me an error : Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '17/12/2008 00:24:39' for function str_to_date